# Device breaks when using my domain name for confirmation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, devise

I have Devise set up on my app to handle sign-ups/confirmation emails and sign-ins. My domain `www.mydomain.com` is mapped to my production app at `production-myapp.herokuapp.com`

Everything was fine, but now, if I change

```
config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => 'production-myapp.herokuapp.com' }
```

to

```
config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => 'http://www.mydomain.com' }
```

Devise breaks when it tries to return the user to the domain name after confirmation. Obviously I don't want to return users to the `production-myapp.herokuapp.com` url because that's just confusing.

Does anyone know how I can fix this to work with my domain name? Thanks!

Comment: don't use a URL? remove the `http://` portion...

Comment: Why wouldn't I use a URL? - it's a live app. Removing 'http://' makes no difference.

Comment: remove `http://www.` using host `config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { host: "mydomain.com" }` [read here](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionMailer/Base.html#config.action_mailer.default_url_options)